# Calculate 7day realized volatility for Dataframe with daily log returns

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataframe consisting of daily log returns for multiple time series. I want to calculate the 7-day realized volatility for each time series column for every week.
Is there a fast way to get this done?

I tried multiple solutions suggested here but could not figure it out.
Many thanks!

MyData looks as follows:

```
structure(list(ADA = c(0.00519787736925448, 0.0307208647325365, 
0.154138771350992, 0.0164342066551776, -0.0557120045069119, 0.0137042340758324, 
-0.00923274693800846, -0.0560696427736868, -0.0453846430358594, 
-0.0119861841881651), BNB = c(-0.0231997754459639, 0.0439663779991935, 
0.0685574769535244, -0.0310282134011945, 0.443641921228532, 0.400594784041669, 
-0.189571775497508, -0.0203461395784901, -0.0450853757768916, 
-0.00114121883972107), BTC = c(-0.0358973950143717, 0.0925827850343683, 
0.0145041249453595, 0.025856749062152, 0.110937798087752, 0.00557805699941127, 
-0.0617370565817161, -0.082670269191885, -0.0386173267907015, 
0.0255604355626176)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example? That makes it easier for people to give you relevant help that corresponds to your specific situation. It's often easiest to do that using the `dput` function. If you have a data frame called MY_DATA, you could run `dput(head(MY_DATA,10))` and paste the code it outputs into the body of your question. That code will let us load an exact copy of the first 10 rows of your data, underlying data formats and all.

Comment: I edited my post. Sry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using the `dplyr` and `slider` packages. This says, "take the `df` data frame, and make a new calculation across all the columns, namely to calculate the standard deviation for sliding windows that include the current row and the prior 6 rows." I included the `.complete = TRUE` parameter for demonstration purposes, to show that a full week is only available starting in row 7. Leave that out if partial week calculations are desired.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~slider::slide(.x, sd, .before = 6, .complete = TRUE)))

          ADA       BNB        BTC
1        NULL      NULL       NULL
2        NULL      NULL       NULL
3        NULL      NULL       NULL
4        NULL      NULL       NULL
5        NULL      NULL       NULL
6        NULL      NULL       NULL
7  0.06446347 0.2340761 0.06271089
8  0.07098292 0.2338244 0.07171482
9  0.07367002 0.2398689 0.06488029
10  0.0312373  0.242319 0.06552966
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe I did not articulate my question in the right way. (English is not my first language) I want to calculate the realized volatility for each week and get the Output. For example if I have 70 observations, I would get 7 results for the realized volatilty. So for every week. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You could add `%>% filter(row_number() %% 7 == 0)` to just keep every 7th row. Depending on the exchange, you might really want 5 day windows then if there are only 5 trading days per week...